# Visualforce Wrapper Object bound Lookup Input:Field Not Setting

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I currently have a wrapper object that contains a `Contact` that will be bound to an `input:Field` in order to create a lookup for an `Account`. Currently the lookup field functions just fine, BUT then when I submit the form (with the value from the lookup page), the `PageReference` method doesn't recognize the value, it is as if it is never set

**List of wrapper objects used on page:**

```
List<WrapperObj> myWrapperList = new List<WrapperObj>();
```

**Controller Wrapper**

```
public class WrapperObj{

        public String label { get; set; }
        public String type  { get; set; }
        public String param { get; set; }
        public String value { get; set; }

        /* Register Lookup field types */
        public Contact contact { get; set; }

        /* ALSO tried setting the value with a private setter */
        // public Contact contact { get; 
           // set{ System.debug('::CONTACT:: '+value); }
        // }

        public WrapperObj(String expression){
            List<String> parts = expression.Split('\\.');
            this.label = parts[0];
            this.type  = parts[1];
            this.param = parts[2];

            /* Account Lookup */
            this.contact = new Contact(); 
        }
}
```

**Page Reference Method:**

```
public PageReference formAction(){
    System.debug(myWrapperList);
}
```

So again the question is why does my wrapper class not have a value stored for the `Contact` object when I submit the page. Also here is the Visualforce markup in case it matters:

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:PageBlock>

        <apex:repeat value="{!myWrapperList}" var="field">

            <apex:outputPanel layout="inline">{!field.label}:</apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!field.contact.AccountId}" />
            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:repeat>

        <!-- Form Submission -->
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="{!search}" action="{!formAction}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:PageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: What this line means `public Contact { get; set; }` ? can't see a variable name. Also try replacing `AccountId` with Account` in VF page. i.e. `<apex:inputField value="{!field.contact.Account}" />`

Comment: Ae you sure that `myWrapperList` is only initialised once and is kept in the view state by being a non-transient and non-static field?

Answer (score 1):

Below are some corrections that should make it work

```
public class WrapperObj{
    public String label { get; set; }
    public String type  { get; set; }
    public String param { get; set; }
    public String value { get; set; }

    public Contact conObj { get; set;}


    public WrapperObj(String expression){
        List<String> parts = expression.Split('\\.');
        this.label = parts[0];
        this.type  = parts[1];
        this.param = parts[2];

        /* Account Lookup */
        this.conObj = new Contact(); 
    }
}
```

and on VF side

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:PageBlock>

        <apex:repeat value="{!myWrapperList}" var="field">

            <apex:outputPanel layout="inline">{!field.label}:</apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!field.conObj.AccountId}" />
            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:repeat>

        <!-- Form Submission -->
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="{!search}" action="{!formAction}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:PageBlock>
</apex:form
```

>

Comment: What changed? not sure I'm spotting the difference here

Comment: check out the way Contact object is used now.

Comment: Oh you fixed my typo?... it is already `public Contact contact { get; set; }`

Comment: So another look at my code and I think that things were actually working just fine but that I was checking the wrong values in my action method. Is there a way to setup custom setter so that when the `Contact.AccountId` gets set I can use that value to set the `WrapperObj.value`?